# Building Boost for iOS in a CMake Superbuild - Post-Build Processing Dependency

Tags: cmake

I'm working on getting Boost built in a superbuild, but Boost insists on compiling with the `-arch arm` (and all other architectures must be added manually) which includes `armv4t` in the binary. So, post-build I want to roll through the libraries and use lipo to remove the invalid architectures. In CMake is there no way to do this within CMake?

It seems I must `add_custom_command` and call `cmake -P` which makes this much uglier especially as I want to include x86 and extend it to Android. Is it possible to run cmake scripts after `ExternalProject_Add` without `cmake -P`?

```
include( ExternalProject )

set( NCPU 8 )
set( MIN_IOS_VERSION 8.0 )
set( BOOST_VERSION 1.63.0 )
set( BOOST_SHA_CHECKSUM 9f1dd4fa364a3e3156a77dc17aa562ef06404ff6 )
set( BOOST_COMPILE_LIBRARIES filesystem system date_time )
set( COMPILE_ARCHITECTURES armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 )
set( ENABLE_BITCODE true )

string( REPLACE "." "_" BOOST_FILENAME "boost_${BOOST_VERSION}" )

set( boost_URL "http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/${BOOST_VERSION}/${BOOST_FILENAME}.tar.bz2" )
set( boost_INSTALL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third_party/boost )
set( boost_INCLUDE_DIR ${boost_INSTALL}/include )
set( boost_LIB_DIR ${boost_INSTALL}/lib )

execute_process( COMMAND xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path
    COMMAND tr -d '\r\n'
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE XCODE_ROOT )

execute_process( COMMAND xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find clang++
    COMMAND tr -d '\r\n'
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE CLANG_PATH )

execute_process( COMMAND xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
    COMMAND tr -d '\r\n'
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE XCODE_SYSROOT )

execute_process( COMMAND xcodebuild -showsdks
    COMMAND grep iphoneos 
    COMMAND egrep "[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+" -o
    COMMAND tail -1
    COMMAND tr -d '\r\n'
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE IOS_SDK_VERSION )

message( STATUS "IOS SDK Version ${IOS_SDK_VERSION}" )

string( REPLACE ";" "," BOOST_WITH_LIBRARIES "${BOOST_COMPILE_LIBRARIES}" )
message( STATUS "Compile Boost libraries ${BOOST_WITH_LIBRARIES}" )

set( COMPILEFLAGS )
foreach( COMPILE_ARCHITECTURE ${COMPILE_ARCHITECTURES} )
    set( COMPILEFLAG "<compileflags>\"-arch ${COMPILE_ARCHITECTURE}\"" )
    list( APPEND COMPILEFLAGS ${COMPILEFLAG} )
endforeach( COMPILE_ARCHITECTURE )

if( ENABLE_BITCODE )
list( APPEND COMPILEFLAGS "<compileflags>-fembed-bitcode" )
endif( ENABLE_BITCODE )
string( REPLACE ";" "\n" COMPILEFLAGS_FINAL "${COMPILEFLAGS}" )

set( USER_CONFIG_JAM
"using darwin : ${IOS_SDK_VERSION}~iphone :
${CLANG_PATH} :
<striper>
<root>${XCODE_ROOT}/Developer
<compileflags>-mios-version-min=${MIN_IOS_VERSION}
<compileflags>-std=c++11
<compileflags>-stdlib=libc++
<compileflags>-fvisibility-inlines-hidden
<compileflags>--sysroot=${XCODE_SYSROOT}
${COMPILEFLAGS_FINAL}
\;
" )
file( WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/user-config.jam ${USER_CONFIG_JAM} )

ExternalProject_Add( external_boost
        PREFIX boost
        URL ${boost_URL}
        URL_HASH SHA1=${BOOST_SHA_CHECKSUM}
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh
            --with-libraries=${BOOST_WITH_LIBRARIES}
            --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove <SOURCE_DIR>/tools/build/src/user-config.jam
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/user-config.jam <SOURCE_DIR>/tools/build/src/user-config.jam
        BUILD_COMMAND ./b2
            -d+2
            -j${NCPU}
            --reconfigure
            architecture=arm
            address-model=32_64
            toolset=darwin
            target-os=iphone
            macosx-version=iphone-${IOS_SDK_VERSION}
            define=_LITTLE_ENDIAN
            link=static
            variant=release
            install
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_DIR ${boost_INSTALL} )

set( BOOST_LIBRARY_SUFFIX .a )

# Expected output filenames for the boost libraries
set( BOOST_RESULT_LIBRARIES )
foreach( BOOST_COMPILE_LIBRARY ${BOOST_COMPILE_LIBRARIES} )
    set( LIBRARY_NAME libboost_${BOOST_COMPILE_LIBRARY}${BOOST_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} )
    list( APPEND BOOST_RESULT_LIBRARIES ${LIBRARY_NAME} )
endforeach( BOOST_COMPILE_LIBRARY )
add_dependencies( BOOST_COMPILE_LIBRARY external_boost )

# Check each static library for the included architectures and toss anything that shouldn't be included
foreach( BOOST_RESULT_LIBRARY ${BOOST_RESULT_LIBRARIES} )
    execute_process( COMMAND lipo -info ${boost_LIB_DIR}/${BOOST_RESULT_LIBRARY}
        COMMAND egrep "armv?[[:digit:]]+[[:lower:]]*" -o
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE ARCHIVE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURES )
    string(REGEX REPLACE "[\r\n]+" ";" ARCHIVE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURES ${ARCHIVE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURES} )
    set( REMOVE_ARCHITECTURES )
    foreach( ARCHIVE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE ${ARCHIVE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURES} )
        list( FIND COMPILE_ARCHITECTURES ${ARCHIVE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE} CONTAINS_ARCHITECTURE )
        if( NOT CONTAINS_ARCHITECTURE )
            list( APPEND REMOVE_ARCHITECTURES ${ARCHIVE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE} )
        endif( NOT CONTAINS_ARCHITECTURE )
    endforeach( ARCHIVE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE )
    foreach( REMOVE_ARCHITECTURE ${REMOVE_ARCHITECTURES} )
        execute_process( COMMAND lipo -remove ${REMOVE_ARCHITECTURE} -output ${BOOST_RESULT_LIBRARY} )
    endforeach( REMOVE_ARCHITECTURE )
endforeach( BOOST_RESULT_LIBRARY )

message( STATUS "${LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURES}" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Boost will always inject `-arch arm` no matter what you'd prefer. In the end I switched to using a shell script to build Boost and clean it up. Given that Boost has its own build system, this is probably as good as it gets.

The following code uses cmake to download and kick off the Boost compilation script.

### boost.cmake

```
include( ExternalProject )

set_property( DIRECTORY PROPERTY EP_BASE third_party )

set( BOOST_URL "http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.63.0/boost_1_63_0.tar.bz2" )
set( BOOST_SHA1 "9f1dd4fa364a3e3156a77dc17aa562ef06404ff6" )
set( BOOST_INSTALL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/boost )
set( BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR ${BOOST_INSTALL}/include )
set( BOOST_LIB_DIR ${BOOST_INSTALL}/lib )

list( APPEND DEPENDENCIES external_boost )
set( DEPENDENCIES "${DEPENDENCIES}" PARENT_SCOPE )
ExternalProject_Add( external_boost
        PREFIX boost
        URL ${BOOST_URL}
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/lipo-library.sh <SOURCE_DIR>
        BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/boost-compile.sh <SOURCE_DIR> <INSTALL_DIR>
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_DIR ${BOOST_INSTALL} )

list( APPEND EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS
        -DBOOST_ROOT=${BOOST_INSTALL}
        -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON )
set( EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS "${EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS}" PARENT_SCOPE )
```

### boost-compile.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE_DIR="$1"
INSTALL_DIR="$2"

BOOST_MODULES=( "date_time" "system" "filesystem" )
VERBOSE_LOGGING=false
FORCE_REBUILD=true
NCPU=8

MIN_IOS_VERSION="8.0"
ENABLE_BITCODE=true

ARCHITECTURE_FAMILIES=( "arm" "x86" )
X86_COMPILE_ARCHITECTURES=( "i386" "x86_64" )
ARM_COMPILE_ARCHITECTURES=( "armv7" "armv7s" "arm64" )
ALL_ARCHITECTURES=( "${X86_COMPILE_ARCHITECTURES[@]}" "${ARM_COMPILE_ARCHITECTURES[@]}" )

echo "Building Boost libraries ${BOOST_MODULES[*]}"
RESULTS_DIRECTORIES=()
for ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY in "${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILIES[@]}"; do
    SDK=""
    TARGET_OS="iphone"
    if [[ "${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY}" == "arm" ]]; then
        SDK="iphoneos"
        SDK_SHORT="iphone"
    elif [[ "${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY}" == "x86" ]]; then
        SDK="iphonesimulator"
        SDK_SHORT="iphonesim"
    fi

    XCODE_PLATFORM_PATH="$(xcrun --sdk ${SDK} --show-sdk-platform-path )"
    XCODE_IOS_CLANG_PATH="$( xcrun --sdk ${SDK} -f clang++ )"
    XCODE_SDK_VERSION="$( xcrun --sdk ${SDK} --show-sdk-version )"

    PLATFORM_NAME="darwin"
    TOOLSET_PREFIX="${PLATFORM_NAME}"
    TOOLSET_SUFFIX="${XCODE_SDK_VERSION}~${SDK_SHORT}"
    TOOLSET="${TOOLSET_PREFIX}-${TOOLSET_SUFFIX}"
    MACOSX_VERSION="${SDK_SHORT}-${XCODE_SDK_VERSION}"

    if [[ "${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY}" == "arm" ]]; then
        SDK_LONG="iPhoneOS${XCODE_SDK_VERSION}.sdk"
#        TOOLSET="${TOOLSET_PREFIX}"
    elif [[ "${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY}" == "x86" ]]; then
        SDK_LONG="iPhoneSimulator${XCODE_SDK_VERSION}.sdk"
    fi
    echo "Using toolset ${TOOLSET}"

    RESULTS_DIRECTORY="${INSTALL_DIR}/${SDK_LONG}-${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY}"
    mkdir -p "${RESULTS_DIRECTORY}"

    CXXFLAGS=()
    if [[ "${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY}" == "arm" ]]; then
        for ARM_COMPILE_ARCHITECTURE in "${ARM_COMPILE_ARCHITECTURES[@]}"; do
            CXXFLAGS+=( "-arch ${ARM_COMPILE_ARCHITECTURE}" )
        done
    fi

    USER_CONFIG_JAM=()
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "using ${TOOLSET_PREFIX} : ${TOOLSET_SUFFIX} :" )
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "${XCODE_IOS_CLANG_PATH} :" )
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "<striper>" )
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "<root>${XCODE_PLATFORM_PATH}/Developer" )
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "<compileflags>-std=c++11" )
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "<compileflags>-stdlib=libc++" )
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "<compileflags>-fvisibility-inlines-hidden" )
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "<compileflags>-mios-version-min=${MIN_IOS_VERSION}" )
    if [[ "${ENABLE_BITCODE}" ]]; then
        USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( "<compileflags>-fembed-bitcode" )
    fi
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( ": <architecture>${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY} <target-os>${TARGET_OS}" )
    USER_CONFIG_JAM+=( ";" )

    USER_CONFIG_STRING=$( IFS=$'\n'; echo "${USER_CONFIG_JAM[*]}" )
    echo "Creating ${SOURCE_DIR}/tools/build/src/user-config.jam"
    echo "${USER_CONFIG_STRING}" > "${SOURCE_DIR}/tools/build/src/user-config.jam"

    WITH_LIBRARIES=$( IFS=$','; echo "${BOOST_MODULES[*]}" )

    echo "Boostrap Boost"
    BOOTSTRAP_OPTIONS=()
    BOOTSTRAP_OPTIONS+=( "--with-libraries=${WITH_LIBRARIES}" )
    BOOTSTRAP_OPTIONS+=( "--prefix=${RESULTS_DIRECTORY}" )

    ./bootstrap.sh "${BOOTSTRAP_OPTIONS[@]}"
    ./b2 --clean-all

    echo "B2 Boost"
    B2_OPTIONS=()
    if [[ "${VERBOSE_LOGGING}" ]]; then
        B2_OPTIONS+=( "-d+2" )
    fi
    if [[ "${FORCE_REBUILD}" ]]; then
        B2_OPTIONS+=( "-a" )
    fi
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "-j${NCPU}" )
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "--reconfigure" )
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "architecture=${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY}" )
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "address-model=32_64" )
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "toolset=${TOOLSET}" )
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "target-os=${TARGET_OS}" )
    if [[ "${#CXXFLAGS[@]}" -gt 0 ]]; then
        B2_OPTIONS+=( "cxxflags=${CXXFLAGS[*]}" )
    fi
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "macosx-version=${MACOSX_VERSION}" )

    if [[ "${ARCHITECTURE_FAMILY}" == "arm" ]]; then
        B2_OPTIONS+=( "define=_LITTLE_ENDIAN" )
    fi

    B2_OPTIONS+=( "link=static" )
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "threading=single" )
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "variant=release" )
    B2_OPTIONS+=( "install" )

    echo "./b2 ${B2_OPTIONS[*]}"
    ./b2 "${B2_OPTIONS[@]}"

    RESULTS_DIRECTORIES+=( "${RESULTS_DIRECTORY}" )
done

echo "Create FAT Boost libraries"
FAT_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR="${INSTALL_DIR}/include"
FAT_INSTALL_LIBARY_DIR="${INSTALL_DIR}/lib"
mkdir -p "${FAT_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}" "${FAT_INSTALL_LIBARY_DIR}"

BOOST_LIBRARIES=()
for BOOST_MODULE in "${BOOST_MODULES[@]}"; do
    BOOST_LIBRARIES+=( "libboost_${BOOST_MODULE}.a" )
done

FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATHS=()
for BOOST_LIBRARY in "${BOOST_LIBRARIES[@]}"; do
    FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATH="${FAT_INSTALL_LIBARY_DIR}/${BOOST_LIBRARY}"
    rm -rf "${FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATH}"
    FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATHS=( "${FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATH}" )

    INCLUDES_DIRS=()
    INTERMEDIATES=()
    for RESULTS_DIRECTORY in "${RESULTS_DIRECTORIES[@]}"; do
        INCLUDES_DIRS+=( "${RESULTS_DIRECTORY}/include/" )
        INTERMEDIATES+=( "${RESULTS_DIRECTORY}/lib/${BOOST_LIBRARY}" )
    done

    for INCLUDES_DIR in "${INCLUDES_DIRS[@]}"; do
        cp -R "${INCLUDES_DIR}" "${FAT_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    done

    if [[ "${#INTERMEDIATES[@]}" -gt 0 ]]; then
        lipo -output "${FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATH}" -create "${INTERMEDIATES[@]}"
    fi
done

echo "Cleaning up Boost build intermediates ${RESULTS_DIRECTORIES[*]}"

rm -rf "${RESULTS_DIRECTORIES[@]}"

echo "Validate Boost libraries contain desired architectures ${ALL_ARCHITECTURES[*]}"
SUCCESS=1
for FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATH in "${FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATHS[@]}"; do
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/lipo-library.sh" "${FAT_LIBBOOST_MODULE_INSTALL_PATH}" "${ALL_ARCHITECTURES[@]}"
    SUCCESS=$?
    if [[ ${SUCCESS} -ne 0 ]]; then
        break
    fi
done

exit "${SUCCESS}"
```

### lipo-library.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

contains() {
    local match="$1"
    shift
    local list=( "${@}" )

    for item in "${list[@]}"; do
        if [[ "${item}" == "${match}" ]]; then
            echo true
            return 1
        fi
    done

    echo false
    return 0
}

library="$1"
shift
valid_architectures=( "${@}" )

if [ -z "${library}" ] || [ ! "${#valid_architectures[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <library> <architecture ...>"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Library to check ${library}"
echo "Required architectures ${valid_architectures[*]}"

# Check static library for the included architectures and toss anything that shouldn't be included
declare -a archive_library_architectures=()
# Handle finding the architectures in a static library, fat or not.
read -r -a archive_library_architectures <<< "$( lipo -detailed_info "${library}" |
                                                 grep architecture |
                                                 sed -e 's/.*architecture:\{0,1\} \{0,1\}//' |
                                                 tr '\r\n' ' ' |
                                                 xargs echo -n )"
echo "${library} contains ${archive_library_architectures[*]}"

missing_architectures=()
for valid_architecture in "${valid_architectures[@]}"; do
    has_architecture=$( contains "${valid_architecture}" "${archive_library_architectures[@]}" )
    if [[ "${has_architecture}" = false ]]; then
        missing_architectures+=( "${valid_architecture}" )
    fi
done

if [ "${#missing_architectures[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "${library} missing ${missing_architectures[*]}"
fi

invalid_architectures=()
for archive_library_architecture in "${archive_library_architectures[@]}"; do
    has_architecture=$( contains "${archive_library_architecture}" "${valid_architectures[@]}" )
    if [[ "${has_architecture}" = false ]]; then
        invalid_architectures+=( "${archive_library_architecture}" )
    fi
done

if [ "${#invalid_architectures[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "${library} invalid ${invalid_architectures[*]}"
fi

for invalid_architecture in "${invalid_architectures[@]}"; do
    echo "lipo -remove ${invalid_architecture} -output ${library} $library"
    lipo -remove "${invalid_architecture}" -output "${library}" "$library"
done

lipo "${library}" -verify_arch "${valid_architectures[@]}"
result=$?
if [ "${result}" = 0 ]; then
    echo "Successfully built ${library} with desired architectures"
else
    echo "Failed to build ${library} with desired architectures"
fi

exit "${result}"
```